# Can gradient descent training be used for non-smooth loss functions?

Tags: neural-networks, training, objective-functions, gradient-descent

I have non-smooth loss function $f(x) = \min(x, 0.5)$.

Can gradient descent be used for training neural networks with such functions? Can gradient descent be used for fairly general, mathematically not-nice functions?

PyTorch or TensorFlow can calculate numerically gradients from almost any function, but it is acceptable practice to use general, not-nice loss functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent can be applied to any differentiable loss function irrespective of whether it is convex or non-convex. The "differentiable" requirement ensures that trainable parameters receive gradients that point in a direction that decreases the loss over time.

In the absence of a differentiable loss function, the true gradient must be approximated through other methods. For example, in classification problems, the 0-1 loss function is considered the "true" loss, but it is non-convex and difficult to optimize. Instead, *surrogate loss functions* act as tractable proxies for true loss functions. They are not necessarily worse; negative log-likelihood loss gives a softmax distribution over $k$ classes rather than just the classification boundary.

For your problem specifically, $f(x,a)=min(x,a)$ is not a differentiable loss function. It is not differentiable at $x=0.5$, but the gradient could be estimated through the [subgradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative). In practice, this works because neural networks often don't achieve the local/global minima of a loss function but instead asymptotically decreasing values that achieve good generalization error. Tensorflow and PyTorch use subgradients when fed non-differentiable loss functions. You could also use a smooth approximation of the $min$ function (see [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35191/a-differentiable-approximation-to-the-minimum-function)) to get better gradients.